# What is the correct way to open port 7000 or 7001 for seed nodes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cassandra

I will use port 7001 eventually to enable SSL security, but for the sake of brevity, I will use 7000 for this post.

I successfully managed to make seed nodes communicate with each other by opening port 7000, but there is one thing I'm worried about. When I opened port 7000 on Amazon Web Services, I got a warning as seen in the following picture.[image]

This is because I set the source for port 7000 to Anywhere, so I changed it to My IP later on, but this time I couldn't make seed nodes work.

Is it safe to ignore the warning and set the source for port 7000 to Anywhere?

Is there an additional process I need to take to secure the port 7000 after opening the port like this?

**Update:**

I read [a doc for Security Groups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html) hoping that I would find something useful, but I'm still struggling to solve this.

I have tried assigning each Security Group ID to its respective Source field, even tried assigning default Security Group ID to every Source field in each datacenter, but been failing at running seed nodes.

You can see in the following pic that I assigned Security Group ID `sg-a9518ed4` to the Source field for port 7000.
[image]
What am I doing wrong?

Note that seed nodes always work if I set the Source field for port 7000 to Anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to allow connections to seed nodes from outside your VPC? Or are all the connections to your seed nodes coming from other resources within your AWS VPC? You've currently opened port 7000 to the entire world.

From my (limited) understanding, Cassandra seed nodes are used for database cluster orchestration. If all of your Cassandra nodes are inside your VPC then you need to restrict port 7000 access to only allow traffic originating inside your VPC. The best way to do this is to change the rule's **Source** to **Security Group** and then specify the ID of a security group whose members should have access to Cassandra seed nodes.

Also, make sure you use the Internal IP addresses in your database cluster to keep all the cluster traffic inside your VPC, for security and performance.

Comment: And I do this in AWS VPC.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the private IPs? The security group rules won't work if you are using public IPs or public DNS.

Comment: I was finally able to solve this today. The problem was that I cared too much about inbound traffic in security groups. I had to set outbound traffic to other nodes so that they can communicate with each other. I had to use public IPs for these setups instead of private IPs since seed nodes only can connect to each other through public IPs. Your answer helped me a lot. Thanks.